# PID Changing everytime I try to kill them

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, ps

Hello I created a script to kill processes ordered by age however everytime the PIDs are changing... how can I solve this 
here is my script

```
 #!/bin/bash
    #Argument = -c check -k kill -l list
usage()
{
cat << EOF
usage: $0 options

This script kills all the processes running and leaves the last one sorted by age running.

OPTIONS:
   -c      checks how many proccess are runnig it needs string argument
   -k      Kill all the processes and leaves just the last sorted by age running
   -l      Show the list of procesess to be killed.
EOF
}

CHECK=
KILL=
LIST=

while getopts "hc:k:l:" OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         h)
             usage
             exit 1
             ;;
         c)
             CHECK=$OPTARG
             ps -ef | grep -i $CHECK | wc -l
             ;;

         k)
             KILL=$OPTARG
             T2=$(ps -ef | grep -i "$KILL" | awk '{print $3,$5}' | sort -r +1 | sed 1d |awk '{print $1}')
                for f in $T2; do
                        echo "killing $f"
                        kill $f
                done
             ;;
         l)
             LIST=$OPTARG
             T2=$(ps -ef | grep -i "$LIST" | awk '{print $3,$5}' | sort -r +1 | sed 1d |awk '{print $1}')
                for f in $T2; do
                        echo "PID $f"
                done
               ;;
         ?)
             usage
             exit
             ;;
     esac
done

if [[ -z KILL ]] || [[ -z LIST ]] || [[ -z CHECK ]]
then
     usage
     exit 1
fi
```

and also I don't understand why when I call the script with no arguments the help doesn't show up

Answer (score 1):

The PIDs will change if another program is restarting it when it's killed. This is actually pretty common with daemons.

`usage` is never called because you're checking whether the *strings* `KILL` etc. are empty, not the *variables*. Just add a dollar sign in front of them.